# How to test languages in enterprise wiki?

Tags: office-365, language, enterprise-wiki

We just started an Office 365 site that has Sharepoint.

We have users that read English, French, or German, and I want to configure a site that shows the same content in each language.

Someone said to use an Enterprise wiki site, so I created it and in the site settings, set it's language properties to those three languages.

Now, how do I see what the French page looks like?

**[update]**

So, if I login with a user that has a different locale, I see that all the built-in titles and links are now in the other language, but any content added by the user is not translated.  Also, I note that there is no language subdirectory in the url.

Comment: Does it have to be enterpise wiki or you have some other purposes?

Comment: Yes, this question should be about Enterprise Wiki in partcicular, please.  I have a more general question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145552/how-to-build-a-multi-language-site